# First steps in BPMN 2.0 - Music production diagram

Tags: business, process, bpmn

I'm trying to simulate the hiring process of a record label. Formally, I decided that the steps to do it are these:

1. The artist send its new album to the record label, which will review it and decide if approve it or not.
2. If the record label approves it, they will prepare an interview in order to decide if hire the artist. If the album is not approved, the will reject it and then terminate the process.
3. Once the interview is done, they can reject it (terminating the processes) or send an offer to the artist, which will decide if accept it or not.

This is how I modeled it:
[image]

What do you think about I used the objects in this model? I didn't understand if I need to connect them to other activities or not. About the two messages, I used the one In the artist to communicate to the record label, is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Some immediate issues:

1. What is `request`? It appears out of nowhere, and does not appear to be used.
2. The first `Reject Application` sends a message back to `Submit Application`, but that implies an instantaneous rejection process, which is doubtful in the real world.

   - `Reject Application` has a `no` coming out of it that doesn't make sense.
3. `Schedule Interview` should communicate back to the `artist` when and where the interview is to be held.
4. `Offer rejected` needs to be processed by `Record Label` but doesn't go anywhere.
5. `Offer` should be shared object between `Artist` and `Record Label`.

In general, if you have documents that communicate between entities, then they should have links from both entities. My assumption is that the document would reside in the swim lane of the entity that created the document.